# what`s the difference between combination Multi-armed bandit(CMAB) and "try and statistic"?

Tags: recommendation-engine, reinforcement-learning

what`s the difference between combination Multi-armed bandit(CMAB) and "try and statistic"?

According to my understanding， i thought the CMAB strategy is same to set aside a part of the network traffic to exploit different choices, then statistic and fix the original distribution...

Can anyone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I got some understanding about this.

CMAB is an algorithm that can guarantee to find the result in a limited regret.